# Passing a PDO connection as a session var

Tags: php, pdo

So in the interest of not repeating myself, I only want to create one PDO connection and pass it between pages using a session var.  But when I setup my PDO connection and set the session var, the var is coming back as not set on my next page?

This is the code on my first page:

```
session_start();
try
{
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$dbHostname.";dbname=".$dbDatabase, $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "It seems there was an error.  Please refresh your browser and try again. ".$e->getMessage();
}

$_SESSION['db'] = $db;
```

Then this test code on my next page comes back as not set.

```
session_start();
$db = $_SESSION['db'];

    if(isset($db))echo "set";
    else echo "not set";
```

Any ideas??

The connection is fine because if I call a function from the first page and pass along $db as a parameter, the function works without any problems.  So why would storing the database var as a session not work?  Thank you for any help.

Comment: You want a [persistent connection](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php#example-952).

Comment: You shouldn't do that — it ties up a database connection for an arbitrarily long amount of time where it's just sitting idle waiting for another request from the same user.

Comment: I'm setting up a sign up form and need to check to see if the user's email address is in the database or not when the form is submitted. Then use the connection to submit the form after the email check comes back.

Comment: You do not **need** to use the same connection. Just reconnect.

Comment: @Freethinker: so what's wrong with creating another connection on next page?

Comment: @zerkms: Nothing really, I was just trying to find a way to minimize the number of lines of code and see if one connection could do for all the DB queries needed in a given app.  I didn't realize PDO didn't allow session serialization.  No harm in trying new things though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PDO` does not allow session serialization.  In fact, you should not be able to serialize database connections in the session at all.  If it's really necessary to do that, you can do something like this:

```
class DB {
   private $db;
   private $creds;

   public function __construct($host, $dbname, $user, $pass) {
      $this->creds = compact('host', 'dbname', 'user', 'pass');
      $this->db = self::createLink($host, $dbname, $user, $pass);
   }

   public function __sleep() {
      return array('creds');
   }

   public function __wakeup() {
      $this->db = self::createLink($this->creds['host'] ...
   }

   public static function createLink($host ...
      return new PDO(...
   }
}
```

Comment: Even though I'm sure that this *never* could be necessary to anyone - +1 for magic methods

Comment: returning creds on sleep is pretty clever, but potentially dangerous, right?  Also, can you call `new DB` within the class and that way just have the `__construct` called on `__wakeup`?

Comment: @Anthony dangerous how?  I don't understand your second question either.  `__wakeup` cannot be static.

Comment: @Anthony: nope, `new DB` could create new DB instance, while `DB` instance is what was woken up

Comment: @Explosion Pills: dangerous by having credentials stored in several places

Comment: @ExplosionPills: exactly what zerkms said.  Dangerous in that it implies the credentials are stored in memory between each request, in the session (which is usually `/tmp` so not hard to find), and if it's the same credentials for any and all uses, they are getting stored for every session, etc.  As for the `__wakeup`, I was just saying that the constructor and the `__wakeup` do the same work, so why not have the wakeup reconstruct. But as zerkms mentioned, it's the same object, not a factory, so it can't return a fresh construction of the object.

Answer (score 0):

PHP closes database connection and free the used resources after the page finishes execution. 
Secondly, it's a resource/handler and not really a value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use persistent connections.

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass, array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
));
```

Your application will behave exactly as if the connection was being reconstructed. So no need for you to serialize the connection and pass it around.

But you do need to be careful and close it when the user session is over so it can be released.

What exactly is your need for persistent connections?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a persistent connection, but it is a bad idea. It ties up valuable system resources, might actually get you kicked off of a shared host, and is actually not all that useful. Just close the connection at the end of each page and start a new one at the next page. If you *really, really want it* then the setting for persistent connections is `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT` which must be set to `true` on your PDO object.